# squirrelmail not receiving mail

Tags: email, squirrelmail

my SquirrelMail can send but not able to receive emails. Imap server is Cyrus.

Can anyone please help me to get it working?

What details should i provide?

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = norris.chuck, localhost, localhost.localdomain, $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, fusionsrv07.internal.corp, fusionsrv07
mydomain = norris.chuck
myhostname = fusionsrv07
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/16, 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.1.0/24
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
relay_domains = $mydestination
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/
```

imapd.conf

```
configdirectory: /var/lib/imap
partition-default: /var/spool/imap
admins: cyrus chuck
sievedir: /var/lib/imap/sieve
sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail
hashimapspool: true
sasl_pwcheck_method: saslauthd
sasl_mech_list: PLAIN
tls_cert_file: /etc/pki/cyrus-imapd/cyrus-imapd.pem
tls_key_file: /etc/pki/cyrus-imapd/cyrus-imapd.pem
tls_ca_file: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

/var/log/maillog

```
Oct  2 15:06:29 fusionsrv07 imap[13600]: accepted connection
Oct  2 15:06:29 fusionsrv07 master[14966]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/imapd
Oct  2 15:06:29 fusionsrv07 imap[14966]: executed
Oct  2 15:06:29 fusionsrv07 imap[13600]: login: kkalashnikov.internal.corp [192.168.82.122] cyrus plaintext User logged in
Oct  2 15:06:30 fusionsrv07 imap[13600]: seen_db: user cyrus opened /var/lib/imap/user/c/cyrus.seen
Oct  2 15:06:30 fusionsrv07 imap[13600]: open: user cyrus opened INBOX
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: connect from fusionsrv08.internal.corp[192.168.82.119]
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: 852566D0175: client=fusionsrv08.internal.corp[192.168.82.119]
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/cleanup[14980]: 852566D0175: message-id=<10401072.21412247997511.JavaMail.pro@fusionsrv08>
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/qmgr[31640]: 852566D0175: from=<automation@norris.chuck>, size=969, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: disconnect from fusionsrv08.internal.corp[192.168.82.119]
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: connect from fusionsrv08.internal.corp[192.168.82.119]
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: 95DFA6D0185: client=fusionsrv08.internal.corp[192.168.82.119]
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/local[14981]: 852566D0175: to=<chuck@norris.chuck>, orig_to=<cyrus@norris.chuck>, relay=local, delay=0.1, delays=0.07/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/qmgr[31640]: 852566D0175: removed
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/cleanup[14980]: 95DFA6D0185: message-id=<10401072.21412247997511.JavaMail.pro@fusionsrv08>
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/qmgr[31640]: 95DFA6D0185: from=<automation@norris.chuck>, size=968, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: disconnect from fusionsrv08.internal.corp[192.168.82.119]
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/local[14981]: 95DFA6D0185: to=<chuck@norris.chuck>, orig_to=<vkal@norris.chuck>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.05/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/qmgr[31640]: 95DFA6D0185: removed
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: connect from fusionsrv08.internal.corp[192.168.82.119]
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: A4C356D0175: client=fusionsrv08.internal.corp[192.168.82.119]
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/cleanup[14980]: A4C356D0175: message-id=<10401072.21412247997511.JavaMail.pro@fusionsrv08>
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/qmgr[31640]: A4C356D0175: from=<automation@norris.chuck>, size=969, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: disconnect from fusionsrv08.internal.corp[192.168.82.119]
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/local[14981]: A4C356D0175: to=<chuck@norris.chuck>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.05/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Oct  2 15:06:37 fusionsrv07 postfix/qmgr[31640]: A4C356D0175: removed
Oct  2 15:06:43 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: connect from fusionsrv07.internal.corp[192.168.82.114]
Oct  2 15:06:43 fusionsrv07 postfix/smtpd[14823]: disconnect from fusionsrv07.internal.corp[192.168.82.114]
Oct  2 15:06:47 fusionsrv07 imap[13600]: open: user cyrus opened INBOX
```

Comment: try first with the usual logfiles.

Comment: @DennisNolte added /var/log/maillog to my question

Comment: Just a hunch, but could you maybe throw up the output from 'ls -la /var/spool'?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Postfix` or similar SMTP daemon which both sends AND receives e-mail, it has nothing to do with `Cyrus` or other IMAP daemons. OK, Postfix must be instructed to deliver mail to Cyrus via LMTP or (deprecated) Cyrus `deliver` command, but other than that, Cyrus has nothing to do with receiving mail.

So first check your **SMTP** logs, whatever SMTP daemon you use and wherever you store the logs. Your question lacks lots of detail. Imagine if you should reply to your own question with only the clues you gave use.

Comment: added /var/log/maillog above. I'm sorry for such a confusing question - i'm fairly new to linux. Please tell what else should i provide